# Jersey RESTful web service gradle setup

Tags: java, rest, gradle, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am stuck with creating a gradle project for a RESTful web service using the jersey library. The project configuration should be capable of launching the service inside a jetty application server. I already found a resource: https://github.com/ziroby/jetty-gradle-hello-world

My problem with that solution is, that it uses an outdated version of jersey. I need at least version 2(preferred latest 2.14). I tried to search for new versions on maven central, but in version 2 a lot of artifact names changed, and I am not able to configure it correctly.

Edit:
I do not specifically need a jetty server in my project. It can be any application server, which is suitable for testing and debugging my app. I am using jetty also in production, so it would be nice to use jetty.

**EDIT**: (by peeskillet) - Code from link

build

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    testCompile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.17.1'
    testCompile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.17.1'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.17.1'
}
test {
    exclude '**/*IntegrationTest*'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    include '**/*IntegrationTest*'
    doFirst {
        jettyRun.httpPort = 8080    // Port for test
        jettyRun.daemon = true
        jettyRun.execute()
    }
    doLast {
        jettyStop.stopPort = 8091   // Port for stop signal
        jettyStop.stopKey = 'stopKey'
        jettyStop.execute()
    }
}
```

Test

```
public class HelloIntegrationTest {
    private static String HELLO_URL = "http://localhost:8080/hello";

    @Test
    public void testHello() throws Exception {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(HELLO_URL);
        String response = webResource.get(String.class);

        assertThat(response, is("Hello, World!"));
    }
}
```

Resource

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWebapp {
    private static HelloWorldService helloWorldService = new HelloWorldService();

    @GET()
    public String hello() {
        return helloWorldService.sayHello();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
  <display-name>Jetty Gradle Hello World</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.ziroby.hello.webapp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- <init-param> -->
    <!-- <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name> -->
    <!-- <param-value>true</param-value> -->
    <!-- </init-param> -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### First

Get rid of all the Jersey dependencies you currently have

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    +------------- ======= JUNK ======= ----------------+
    | testCompile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.17.1' |
    | compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1'       |
    | compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.17.1'     |
    | compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.17.1'    |
    +---------------------------------------------------+
}
```

Below is the *only* only one you need to get the basic functionality

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
   +-------------------- ========= GOLDEN ======== -------------------------+
   | compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.14'|
   +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   /* UPDATE */
   /* Starting Jersey version 2.26, you will also need the following */
   /* compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.26' */
}
```

### Second

web.xml

```xml
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ziroby.hello.webapp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### Third

Test

```java
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import org.junit.Test;

public class HelloIntegrationTest {

    private static String HELLO_URL = "http://localhost:8080/hello";

    @Test
    public void testHello() throws Exception {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(HELLO_URL);
        String response = webTarget.request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println(response);
        assertThat(response, is("Hello, World!"));
    }
}
```

---

This has been tested with a clone of the linked project. Only changes are shown above.

**Other Resources:**

- [What exactly is the ResourceConfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435)
- [More information on deployment options](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html)
- [More information in the Client API](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html)

---

#### Update

For JSON support use

```
org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.14
```

No extra configuration is required for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the GitHub version to include these changes.

Comment: after running 'gradle integrationTest', jetty is still runnning, but the commands 'gradle jettyRun' and 'gradle jettyStop' are working fine ... is it the daemon that disturbs there? How can i fix that?

Comment: that "golden" import was not sufficient for me, I had to add a few junk ones